# Auth0 Gmail SS0 doesn't work when I enable Customize Login Page (using auth0 asp.net mvc sample)

Tags: authentication, gmail, single-sign-on, auth0

This is my ASP.NET MVC sample

[image: my sample login page - Image1]

Now I'm clicking log in button and it redirects me to the Auth0 custom login page

[image: auth0 custom login page -Image2]

Now, I'm clicking login with the google button and I already signed in to my Gmail account but it doesn't bring token, and no redirection

URL : https://ishkyteck.us.auth0.com/login?state=hKFo2SBJRWVZQ1F2dk1WeW91Ry1sdVh2SklnQWhVemZjdS1YcKFupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgb1FGXzRoYjR5a2phTmU2dUNEMGFUcmk0YXN4a1dRYjmjY2lk2SBTbjdld3VBcWk4Y3JyWFVTcjQ2bkYxSEJHZmF2VGl0cg&client=Sn7ewuAqi8crrXUSr46nF1HBGfavTitr&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637732441711041622.NjQ3MWUxZTYtMTM4Yy00OTQ1LWEyMzUtMTBmN2Y5NjQ5OWVkMzNjYjllMTItNTMwYi00NmIyLWIyMzEtNTY0MjQzNDk1ODll&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fishkyteck.us.auth0.com%2Fapi%2Fv2%2F&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=6.7.1.0

[image: redirection issue image - Image3]

and it hits the AuthorizationCodeReceived method but does not bring the token

[image: AuthorizationCodeReceived method - Image4]

Please, auth0 community developer look into this bug and resolve. I'm using your provided asp.net MVC sample but it doesn't work.
Sample I downloaded from : https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnet-owin-mvc-samples/tree/master/Quickstart/01-Login/MvcApplication

Please help me. Thank you!!

Issue reproducing sample (my auth0 Gmail SSO sample),
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aHXDCLZjcXth2u1KzON7hhhzKOIv6B0b/view?usp=sharing

When I enable this button, Gmail login does not work in the auth0 universal custom login page
[auth0 custom universal login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgDHc.png)

Comment: Please define doesnt work.  Please include [example]

Comment: @DaImTo this is my sample, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aHXDCLZjcXth2u1KzON7hhhzKOIv6B0b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm using auth0 provided asp.net MVC sample with my auth0 domain, client Id, client secret, and API audience. I've coded nothing in this sample except my auth0 app configuration value. This is the sample I downloaded from the auth0 site https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnet-owin-mvc-samples/tree/master/Quickstart/01-Login/MvcApplication